# Why do I get "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:" from user input?

Tags: python, list

```
n = int(input())
markesheet = [[ int(input()).split()] for _ in range(n)]
print (markesheet)
```

The user has to enter n = `2`, then for markesheet, the user has to enter 2 numbers `22 33`.

The desired output is `[22,33]`.

I am getting error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: Does the user enter ```n = 2``` or just ```2```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about the order in which things are happening here:

- `input()` gets the string that the user types in
- `int()` tries to take that string type object and turn it into an int type object. (gives ValueError because `'22 33'` doesn't make sense as a integer, it's two separate numbers)
- `.split()` doesn't make sense and isn't defined for an int type

Instead, you probably want this:

- get a string from `input()`
- `split()` that string into a list of smaller strings
- turn each string into an int

The code for that looks like the following:

```
markesheet = [ int(_) for _ in input().split() ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the user enters `22 23`, the function `input()` will try to interpret the entire string `22 23` as an integer. But apparently, `22 23` is not a valid integer, so you get that error.

Therefore, you need to modify how `markesheet` is constructed:

```
n = int(input())
markesheet = [int(s) for s in input().split()[:n]]
print(markesheet)
```